# Removing associations with Doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I'm using Doctrine and have three tables. `artists`, `categories`, `artist_category`. I have an import script which imports artists, categories and the associations from a site  and saves it into the database. The problem I'm having is removing an association. Let's just imagine I have one artist and this artist is associated with three categories. Now in the next import one `artist_category` association got removed. What I want to do now is to remove the categories from the association table that aren't relevant anymore.

Let's say my artist has the ID 254 and the category that should be removed has the ID 4.

My database table currently looks like this

[image]

Now I have an array with all categories that the artist should be associated with

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "3"
}
```

This would mean, that in my next step I have to remove the association artist_id (254) and artistcategory_id (4).

What I'm doing is this

```
foreach ($artist->getArtistCategories() as $artistCategory) {
    if (!in_array($artistCategory->getId(), $artistCategories)) {
        $artist->removeArtistCategories($artistCategory->getId());
    }
}
```

which is working. In the case of category 4 the method `removeArtistCategories` is called. However, the deletion doesn't work. This is what I tried

```
$this->artistCategories->removeElement($artistCategory);
```

returns false

```
$this->artistCategories->remove($artistCategory);
```

returns null

```
$this->artistCategories->contains($artistCategory)
```

returns false

However, when I `var_dump($this->artistCategories)` I'm getting pretty much information about the categories. Deletion however, doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine works with entity objects, not with IDs. So instead:

```
$artist->removeArtistCategory($artistCategory->getId());
```

try

```
$artist->removeArtistCategory($artistCategory);
```

and define your remover like described in the Doctrine documentation:

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#association-management-methods

```
public function removeArtistCategory(Category $category) {
    $this->artistCategories->removeElement($category);
}
```

Note that I renamed the method `removeArtistCategories` to `removeArtistCategory` as you just remove one entry and not multiple categories. This is important because `removers` and `adders` have a naming convention just like `getters` and `setters` and you will have problems using some components for doctrine if you don't define your methods correctly.

I just assumed you have a toMany relationship between `Artist` and `Category` because I don't know your entity definition, I'd need more information to give you a proper solution. So this code is untested and might not work!

Comment: Hi, thanks, this is working! For the naming conventions: I didn't name the methods, it's a almost finished project I'm working on and I'm just going with the naming conventions of the project.

Comment: @StoryTeller Is there a documentation somewhere about this naming convention?

Comment: You can see the convention in the documentation in the post, though it is not mentioned specifically in the description. I noticed I have to use this convention during usage of hydrations in Zend 2. In some of the internal code you'll find lines like `$method = "remove" . ucfirst($property)`, converting the property name into a method, which wouldn't work anymore if you define those methods in plural instead of singular.